# JSF Generic error screen with message passed

Tags: jsf-2, error-handling, resourcebundle, forward, dispatch

I have a jsf application where I do some code in the @PostConstruct method:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        // Do some form preparation
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("error.faces");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

and I have this error.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/templates/main.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        <title>#{msg['page.title']}</title>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">
        #{msg['global.error']}
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

now I want the "global.error" and "page.title" not to be static as resource bundles, instead I should pass the message I want somewhere in the post construct so that the error.xhtml can read and display, the reason for this is that this screen should be referred from all the screens, so a search screne can display "error while seaching" and another screen can display "error while fetching data" or "the user you requested does not exist in our system"

Answer (score 0):

You could use `#{flash}` to achieve your functionality:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        // Do some form preparation
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("title", "Custom title");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("error", "Custom error description");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("error.faces");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

with view:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/templates/main.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        <title>#{flash['title']}</title>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">
        #{flash['error']}
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

This approach will work while doing a redirect as well.

Alternatively, you could as well populate a bean with both messages as fields and attach it as a request attribute, if you are doing a forward, and access it in a usual fashion in your error view.

Comment: you solution sounds great, I just solved it this way:

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("error.faces?message=error.loading.screen");

what do you think ??

Comment: IMO I don't think it's a good idea to pass error ids as query parameters, especially if there is a clearer solution.

Comment: Okay i didn't read about the flash object yet but since it's the cleaner solution then I'll go for it

Comment: It's your project and it's up for you to decide. But be sure on one topic: it's *definitely worth* reading about flash object.

Comment: but I did not use the redirect I'm using dispatch instead

Comment: It works on a forward as well. Also, you could instantiate a message and attach it as a request attribute and it'd be a clearer solution, as stated in the last paragraph above.

Comment: I did not work on forward it only worked on redirect, I wonder how this code runs with you ?